Correctly removing double vertices
A lot of times I come across models with double vertices. The best method I've tried is selecting non-manifold vertices and then merging by distance. However, this method sometimes merges boundaries that are supposed to be there. Is there a more effective method for this?

I think we have to have some  clue about what would discriminate between the doubles you do want to remove and the doubles you don't want to remove, before we can answer this. Could you provide an illustration of a typical failing case?

In addition to @RobinBetts comment: Do you know that you can set the Merge Distance in the panel that appears in the bottom left of the screen after you have done the Merge? You might get the result you want by lowering the value until the parts you don't want to merge, don't merge.
